# Microsoft Edge 44.18362.387.0 - SCRIPT12017: WebSocket Error connecting to wss://localhost:8990/ws

Tags: localhost, microsoft-edge, websocket

1. I have run the CheckNetIsolation commands suggested.

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -p=S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-73798

2. I have verified that in the about:flags localhost loopback is enabled.
3. When I try to connect to the localhost Websocket

var fullurl = "wss://localhost:8990/ws"; // secure web socket
conn = new WebSocket(fullurl);

I get the following error.

SCRIPT12017: SCRIPT12017: WebSocket Error: SECURITY_ERR, Cross zone connection not allowed

Here is the results of running  CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -s
[1] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: AppContainer NOT FOUND
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3940530315-3680572922-3580967311-3604442549-2808734947-326342994-2786341419

[2] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194

[3] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: AppContainer NOT FOUND
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194-4043415302-551583165-304772019-4009825106

[4] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: AppContainer NOT FOUND
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194-3859068477-1314311106-1651661491-1685393560

[5] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: 001
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194-4256926629-1688279915-2739229046-3928706915

[6] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    SID:  S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194

OK.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 changes that helped me fix the issue and establish a localhost WebSocket connection.

1. In the Control Panel - Internet Option, select the Security Tab. In the Security tab, select Local intranet zone. Click on Sites button and uncheck all checkboxes in Local intranet dialog. OR
2. In the Control Panel - Internet Option, select the Security Tab. In the Security tab, select Local intranet zone. Click on Sites button and then on Advanced button in the Local intranet dialog, add the required web address to the same zone as localhost.

I would like to know how I could get it to work by adding the web address and the local web socket address to the Trusted sites list?  I could not get it to successfully establish a WebSocket connect using this approach.

Comment: 1st point Worked for me. Are there any side effects of this? Thanks in advance